# Prevent the middle container from sinking into the bottom container

Tags: html, css

I thought I found a way to prevent the middle container from sinking into the top container and the bottom container when you resize the window

but I realize the way I messed with the margins and the way I have my CSS it is only working for the top container so how can I have it to work for the bottom container to meaning

to prevent the middle container from sinking into the bottom container that's why my scroll bar is cutting off. I made

the bottom container transparent like so you guys can see what I mean and yes I am aware that if I keep shrinking

the window size the top container and the bottom container will collide with each other eventually. Which I don't mind especially since

the middle container will look like its gone when you shrink the window to much which I don't care either

I'm just focusing on if you can still see the middle container still.

Here is my code

```css
#container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top-container{
  background-color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#middle-container{
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  
  height: 87%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  
}

#bottom-container{
background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);

  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  
  <div id='top-container'></div><!--</top-container>-->
  
      <div id='middle-container'>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
  </div><!--</middel-container>-->
  
  <div id='bottom-container'></div><!--</bottom-container>-->
      
</div><!--</container>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set height or margins of #middle-container. Its position is absolute so `top: 50px` makes it start just after #top-container (wich has height 50px) and `bottom: 50px` makes it end just before #bottom-container.

```css
#container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top-container{
  background-color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#middle-container{
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  
}

#bottom-container{
background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);

  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  
  <div id='top-container'></div><!--</top-container>-->
  
      <div id='middle-container'>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
        <h1>x</h1>
  </div><!--</middel-container>-->
  
  <div id='bottom-container'></div><!--</bottom-container>-->
      
</div><!--</container>-->
```